# Windows Batch file get filesystem info without elevated priveledges

Tags: windows, filesystems, batch, non-admin

I have a batch file that needs to check the filesystem and choose options for a program it's running based on the filesystem (which could be NTFS or FAT32 in this environment). For Windows systems I have admin privileges on, I can use 'fsutils fsinfo' to get filesystem info - but I have users without admin privileges that may need to run this batch file, and machines I may not necessarily have admin privileges to, either. Is there an equivalent to 'fsutils fsinfo' that can get (but obviously not write, as fsutils can) file system info for a non-admin user?

Comment: Look at this stackoverflow question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995813/how-can-i-use-batch-to-determine-if-a-computer-is-using-fat32-or-ntfs

Comment: Thank you, maudam. Doesn't get me exactly what I'm looking for in just a batch file (I hate to rely on generating an error to get the answer), but I think I can make the vbs version in that link work. Endgame is the same.

Comment: I chose JosefZ's answer as it addressed my original question (better than my own answer), doing this entirely within a batch file and further without relying on error catching to do so. I do, however, appreciate the help from Maudam and the VBS based answer from paxdiablo via Maudam's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippet:

```
for /F %%G in ('
    wmic path win32_volume where "Caption='C:\\'" get FileSystem /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%g in ("%%~G") do set "_%%~g"
set _FileSystem
```

**Output**:

```
==>for /F %G in ('wmic path win32_volume where "Caption='C:\\'" get FileSystem /value
^|findstr "="') do @for /F %g in ("%~G") do @set "_%~g"

==>set _FileSystem
_FileSystem=NTFS

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

**Edit** to get file system for all *live* drives:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
rem SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /F %%X in ('
    wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk get caption /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %%x in ("%%~X") do (

  for /F %%G in ('
      wmic path win32_volume where "Caption='%%~x:\\'" get FileSystem /value^|findstr "="
    ') do for /F %%g in ("%%~G") do set "_%%~x-%%~g"

)
set _
```

**Output**

```
==>set _
Environment variable _ not defined

==>D:\bat\SU\929159.bat
_C-FileSystem=NTFS
_D-FileSystem=NTFS
_E-FileSystem=CDFS

==>set _
_C-FileSystem=NTFS
_D-FileSystem=NTFS
_E-FileSystem=CDFS

==>
```

Comment: I like that this is a pure batch file implementation. I can take this, and I can generate the file system by replacing what's inside the single quotes after "Caption=" with one of my drive letters. One issue, the way this will get run, it's actually being based on a file and what drive the file is on. I used the left(arg,2) in my VBS script to just take just the drive letter. Here, It has to have two '\' after the drive letter. If a full path is being passed as a parameter to this batch file, how do I get it to check the drive properly? (the ways i'm trying keep getting errors)

Comment: Well, I just looked at your list of resources and saw I just needed to replace C: with %~d1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution that also worked for me, though it wasn't done purely with a batch file:

In VBS File 'GetFileSys.vbs':

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colVols = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

For Each arg in args
    For Each objVol in colVols
        if objvol.Name = left(arg,2) then
            Wscript.Echo objVol.FileSystem
        end if
    Next
Next
```

(The top portion I borrowed from paxdiablo via the link provided by Maudam, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995813/how-can-i-use-batch-to-determine-if-a-computer-is-using-fat32-or-ntfs , then adapted to my needs)

Then, In the batch file, I called the VBS file with cscript like so:

```
cscript //NoLogo GetFileSys.vbs %1 %2 %3
```

Results:

```
NTFS
FAT32
ReFS
```

(I didn't even realize my system was using ReFS until I ran this)